# Converting Variables In List to Local Variables

Tags: python

Is there any way to convert variables in a list to local variables in python?

More specifically, I've been doing

```
x = imp.load_source("test","./test")
```

but I don't want to have to do `x.var1`

I just want to be able to do `var1` to reference each imported element.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's wrong with `x.var1`?

Comment: One horrible way would be `locals().update({'monkey': 1})`.

Comment: If you know the number of imported elements you'll get, you could do something silly like `var1, var2, var3 ... = imp.load_source("test","./test")`

Comment: Updating the `locals()` dict does not work. From the docs: "Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, and I'm not sure what you're trying to do is a good idea (think of the Zen of Python: "Namespaces are one honking great idea--let's do more of those!"). Are you trying to load files of Python source code and have access to their local variables?

Again, I am going to reiterate by warning that these are bad ideas.

A. Why are you using the imp module? Just import the module like normal. Then take all of it's local scope and import it into your local scope:

```
from test import *
```

This is the classic example of bad Python. Don't do it. Every Python programmer will tell you never to use from *_* import *. It will accomplish what you're trying to do, but you'll likely override local variables or even built-ins and cause obscure bugs.

B. Use `execfile`. That takes the source of a file and executes it in the local scope. Like so:

```
execfile('./test', globals(), locals())
```

This has the same warnings as the last one: this might override local variables (including built-ins) and cause obscure bugs.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just one variable, then you can do something like this:

```
var1 = x.var1
```

However, if you have a ton of variables, you *could* do

```
from test import *
do_something(var1)
```

where `test` is the original module...but **don't do that**. I know, it sounds counterintuitive, but... [read this](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/why-import-star-is-a-bad-idea/). Frankly, just type the the `x.var1`. How hard is it, really? You'll save yourself a lot of heartache.